# How to use RIL_GetCurrentOperator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile

I'm a bit lost today. I've been trying to find a way to get the name of the operator the user is registered with. Apparently MNC & MCC codes are illegal to retrieve. During my research, I've stumbled upon a miraculous function that may be doing what I need it to do : RIL_GetCurrentOperator() (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921502.aspx) the problem being that I'm a complete newbie concerning mobile programming and that I can't understand this documentation at all. Am I supposed to instantiate an ril ? How do I do so ? Where do I get all the parameters it is asking me to provide ? Should I use a library to include this function ? Can someone please help ?

Comment: I'm now looking into how I can use this class : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation(v=vs.105).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you are referencing is referring to Windows Mobile 6.5. Windows Phone is a completely overhauled platform and that function is not accessible for sandboxed third-party applications.

Windows Phone 7 has a completely different application model than Windows Mobile - all apps are sandboxed and have much less native access to the underlying OS. That being said, RIL_GetCurrentOperator requires privilege escalation that your application simply cannot get without the ability to access the OS (it can't out-of-the-box).

Comment: I'm working on Windows Mobile 7. Isn't it possible to use the function on it ? I'm sorry but would you mind explaining what you meant in a more simple fashion ?

Comment: Den is right.  The short answer is no, you can't use that function under Windows Phone.  Period.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. Is there any other way for me to get my user's operator ? Through MNC or MCC codes ? It's simply a matter of app customization according to the operator.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Note: How about this class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation(v=vs.105).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 ?

Comment: Yes, you can use it. If Windows Phone is marked as a supported platform in the MSDN docs, you can use the class/function.

Comment: Thank you Den, I'm currently installing the tools for WP7.1. I'm confident about this solution =)

Comment: @DenDelimarsky Btw, I was just wondering. Why shouldn't I be able to use RIL ? There's an embedded version for WP7 according to MSDN docs : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee496930.aspx.

Comment: Windows Embedded != Windows Phone

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you for your patience and help Mr.Delimarsky =)